# How can I insert a transparent image using ODS PDF

Tags: image, pdf, sas, transparency, sas-ods

I'm trying to insert an image that has a transparent background into a PDF document using ODS.  When I check the created PDF file, the image is using a white background.  My code looks like this:

```
ods escapechar="~";
ods text="~{STYLE [preimage='transparent_test.gif?width=3.62in&height=1in']}";
```

Answer (score 2):

Use an `SVG` file with a transparent background instead:

```
ods escapechar="~";
ods text="~{STYLE [preimage='transparent_test.svg?width=3.62in&height=1in']}";
```

It does not seems to work with either `gif` nor `png` files, but `svg` should work fine.

Here is the SVG image (external link as neither SO nor imgur support SVG):

http://svgur.com/s/3FU

`goptions transparency;` seemed like it may have shown promise but based on my testing it had no effect.